# Wordpress post object getting page title rather than object title

Tags: wordpress, repeater, advanced-custom-fields, postdata

I have an ACF repeater, which repeats post objects. I am changing the postdata to the post object rather than the page so that i can get the title and thumbnail image. This works perfectly for the first one, however the subsequent objects pull the correct thumbnail but the title is pulled from the page title.

Heres the code:

```
<?php if( have_rows('service_repeater') ): ?>
<?php while ( have_rows('service_repeater') ) : the_row(); ?>

    <?php $post_object = get_sub_field('service'); ?>

    <?php if( $post_object ): ?>
        <?php $post = $post_object; ?>
        <?php setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="service">
            <div class="background" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $url; ?>');"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <p><?php the_field('read_more_text'); ?></p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <?php unset($post_object, $post); ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ok, so i removed the `<?php unset($post_object, $post); ?>` and it worked perfectly. Will this give me problems later on though with regards to variables??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i removed the `<?php unset($post_object, $post); ?>` and it works now. Im concerned that this will give me trouble later down the line with variables however.